# C++ Unable to convert base class to derived class when registering callback

Tags: c++, stl, callback

I’d like to create a map of callbacks to different objects of the same hierarchy but I'm getting the following error:

```
class ResponseBase
{
public:
    virtual bool Parse() = 0;
};

class MyResponse : public ResponseBase
{
public:
    bool Parse() { return true; }
    void SayHello() {}
};

typedef std::tr1::function<void (ResponseBase*)> MYCALLBACK;
typedef std::map<int, MYCALLBACK> MYCALLBACKS;

MYCALLBACKS myCallbacks;

void RegisterCallback(int nType, MYCALLBACK myCallback)
{
    MYCALLBACKS::iterator iter = myCallbacks.find(nType);
    if (iter == myCallbacks.end())
        myCallbacks[nType] = myCallback;
    else
        iter->second = myCallback;
}

void Callback0(ResponseBase *pResponseBase) {}
void Callback1(MyResponse *pMyResponse) {}

int main()
{
    RegisterCallback(0, Callback0); // OK
    RegisterCallback(1, Callback1); // error C2664: 'void (MyResponse *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ResponseBase *' to 'MyResponse *'

    return 0;
}
```

But I'd like to avoid doing something like this:

```
void Callback1(ResponseBase *pResponseBase)
{
    MyResponse *p = static_cast<MyResponse*>(pResponseBase);
    p->SayHello();
}
```

How can I work around the error?

Comment: If you're just calling virtual methods in the objects, then you don't need different callbacks for each inherited class.

Comment: Why would you have to cast anyway? If the types are polymorphic, you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: The problem is, how does the compiler know you won't later try to call `Callback1` with something that isn't an instance of `MyResponse`? How would it even know to try and cast that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to store a set of callbacks to differing object types. You'll need to store a callback object containing an opaque object reference (commonly known as a delegate.) See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218712/how-to-allow-templated-functor-work-on-both-member-and-non-member-functions/17237671#17237671

Comment: @willj-Thanks but is there any other way that doesn't involve templates?

Comment: @willj why not just use `typedef std::function<void(void)> callback;` with `callback a = std::bind(&MyResponse::Parse,&obj);` or `typedef callback std::function<void(MyReposose*)>` with `callback a = std::bind(&MyResponse::Parse,_1); a(&context_obj);`?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Delegates can indeed be implemented with `std::function<void()>` and  `std::bind`, with an additional runtime overhead.

Comment: @jpen: You can't get around it without casting, but you can wrap the cast in a template to make it type-safe. PS. Your example already involves templates - in `std::function` and `std::map` - why are you looking to avoid them?