# Is there a way to deduce the value of a function pointer template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type, template-argument-deduction

C++ allows non-type template parameters to be of pointer, including function pointer, type. I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191103/use-case-for-non-type-template-parameter-thats-not-of-integral-enumeration-type/17654008) about what this is useful for, and this is a follow up to [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654008/141719).

Is it posible to deduce the **value** of a function pointer template parameter, from a function argument that is the function pointer in question? For example:

```
using VoidFunction = void(*)();

template <VoidFunction F>
void templ(VoidFunction);

...

void func();  // a VoidFunction

...

templ<func>(func);  // works, but I have to specify the template parameter explicitly
templ(func);        //  <-- I would like to be able to do this
```

Is there a way to get this deduction to happen? It seems technically possible from a compiler implementer's point of view, as long as the function argument can be resolved to a function in the code at compile time.

If you're wondering about the motivation behind this, see the comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654008/141719), particularly a possible optimization for the implementation of `std::bind()`.

**EDIT**: I realize that I could simply remove the function argument and use the template argument, as in `templ<func>()`. My only purpose of adding in the function argument was to try to avoid having to pass the template argument.

I guess what I really want, is to also deduce the **type** of the function pointer, as in:

```
template <typename Function, Function F>
void templ(/* something */);
```

and then be able to call

```
templ(func);
```

or

```
templ<func>();
```

and have both the type and value be deduced from a single mention of the function pointer.

Hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: How could it deduce it? For example, I could do this: `template<std::size_t N> void foo(std::size_t i) {int arr[N]; /*fill*/ return arr[i];}`. I would definitely want an error if I happened to forget the template argument when this deduction could be done.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure I understand why it needs to be passed as a function argument as well. Isn't `templ<func>();` enough?

Comment: @chris: Right, my question didn't make much sense as written :) Please see my edit.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There was a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) to be able to deduce `T` in `template<using typename T, T t>`, but I don't think it made it in.

Comment: If you are happy passing the function as an argument, why do you also want that same function as a template parameter? What's wrong with `template <typename Function> templ(Function func);` ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: To allow the compiler to perform better optimizations by generating a different instantiation for each function passed as an argument (not just each *type* of function), and then perhaps inlining each if appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template arguments for a function are deduced from the types of the function's template parameters. Template arguments can only be deduced from a type when that type is one of the allowed forms. The allowed forms are specified in [temp.deduct.type]

> Template arguments can be deduced in several different contexts, but in each case a type that is specified in terms of template parameters (call it `P`) is compared with an actual type (call it `A`), and an attempt is made to find template argument values (a type for a type parameter, a value for a non-type parameter, or a template for a template parameter) that will make `P`, after substitution of the deduced values (call it the deduced `A`), compatible with `A`.
>
> A template type argument `T`, a template template argument `TT` or a template non-type argument `i` can be deduced if `P` and `A` have one of the following forms:

```
T
cv-list T
T*
T&
T[integer-constant]
template-name (where template-name refers to a class template)
type(*)(T)
T(*)()
T(*)(T)
T type::*
type T::*
T T::*
T (type::*)()
type (T::*)()
type (type::*)(T)
type (T::*)(T)
T (type::*)(T)
T (T::*)()
T (T::*)(T)
type[i]
template-name<i> (where template-name refers to a class template)
TT<T>
TT<i>
TT<>
```

> where `(T)` represents argument lists where at least one argument type contains a `T`, and `()` represents argument lists where no parameter contains a `T`. Similarly, `<T>` represents template argument lists where at least one argument contains a `T`, `<i>` represents template argument lists where at least one argument contains an `i` and `<>` represents template argument lists where no argument contains a `T` or an `i`.

When considering only non-type template arguments, the relevant forms are those that contain `i`:

```
type[i]
template-name<i> (where template-name refers to a class template)
TT<i>
```

Therefore it is not possible to deduce the value directly from the value of a function argument that is the function pointer. However it **is** possible to deduce the value of a non-type template argument if the function parameter has one of the specified forms.

The following code ahieves this by wrapping the non-type template argument value in a class-template called `NonType`. The parameter of `f` is in the form `template-name<i>`, making it possible for the value of its non-type template argument to be deduced.

```
template<typename T, T value>
struct NonType {};

template<typename T, T value>
void f(NonType<T, value>)
{
}

void g();

struct A
{
    void f();
    int m;
};

int i;

#define MAKE_NONTYPE(value) NonType<decltype(value), (value)>()

int main()
{
    f(MAKE_NONTYPE(0)); // NonType<int, 0>
    f(MAKE_NONTYPE(&g)); // NonType<void(*)(), &g>
    f(MAKE_NONTYPE(&A::f)); // NonType<void(A::*)(), &A::f>
    f(MAKE_NONTYPE(&A::m)); // NonType<int A::*, &A::m>
    f(MAKE_NONTYPE(&i)); // NonType<int*, &i>
}
```

Note that `decltype` and the `MAKE_NON_TYPE` macro are used here only as a convenience, to avoid having to write out the full template argument list of `NonType`